# FXML how to remove borders

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm new in Java developpement (Android excepted) and I use JavaFX with FXML to create interfaces.
I have a Button with an image. I want to remove the border, I tried this way:

```
<Button border="0" background="transparent">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="/resources/images/btn_home.png"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

But I have an exception `Unable to coerce 0 to class javafx.scene.layout.Border` and I'm not able to understand how `border` attribute works. Can you help me?

Last, do you think that use JavaFX for UI application is a good idea? Because I don't found any useful documentation about this library. What's your opinion?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use stylesheets! Then you can use -fx-background-* to set your styles.
You can find some examples here:
http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/

Comment: Ok your answer help me to fix my problem, but can you tell me what do you think about JavaFX and FXML please?

Comment: I like it, am using it myself! I do not have any problems with documentation, when I google for javafx or fxml i always do find usefull documentation. Mostly on docs.oracle.com/javafx (with google as searchengine)